# Kubernetes statefulset analog on Google Compute Engine

Tags: kubernetes, architecture, ansible, google-compute-engine, terraform

Is this a sane idea to create a service with **statefulset**-like architecture outside of the kubernetes?

And is there some way to make this with GCE nowadays?

There would be app pairs, like **backend app + database** with an **index** for each pair. So VMs would have hostnames based on **index + tier**, for example, **3-app** and **3-db**.

Every instance can have metadata like **index + tier + IP address**, and which can be **stored** somewhere and should be **deleted on pair removal**.

And the whole thing can be **managed** (deployed & provisioned) with **Terraform**, **Ansible**, etc or by some Google Cloud service.

**What was done**: an old semi-automated stateful service that tastes like a meatball made of Nginx, Redis and Java and spaghetti of bash, python, and ruby. And it can't be ported to kubernetes, sigh.

Comment: Are you trying to run a kubernetes on GCE?

Comment: @Alioua nope, I'm trying to build two statefulset analogs bound to each other on GCE